# Is there a way to concatenate in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

Is there a simple way to concatenate multiple cells in VBA?

Similar to the function below

Concatenate(A1,"-",B1)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using "&"

```
cells(1,1).value = cells(1,2) & "-" & cells(1,3)
```

Comment: Thank you! Glad the solution was simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098.aspx) function

it's a little trickier since it requires a *"One-dimensional array"* which you get by using `Application.Transpose()` function

but it gets really handy when you need to concatenate many cells, thus saving you a lot of typing and making it possible to exploit all `Range` object properties and methods like `Offset()` (useful in loops), `Resize()` and so on

for example

**1-row range**

```
'_direct_ range reference
Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:B1").Value)), "-")

'_offsetted_ range reference
Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:B1").Offset(i).Value)), "-") '<-- offset "i" rows
```

**1-column range**

```
'_direct_ range reference
Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A2").Value), "-")

'_offsetted_ range reference
Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A2").Offset(i).Value), "-") '<-- offset "i" rows
```